# Requesting AWS Spot Instances best practices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Does anyone have any guidance on what the most efficient way to launch an EMR cluster using EC2 spot instances? I'm using a 10-node r5d.8xlarge (1 master 9 core) and usually I will clone a previous instance. What's been happening more often than not is that I'll get an "out of capacity" error. When that happens I change the subnet and try again. It's really a guessing game at this point and I'm sure there's a much better way to do this, unfortunately I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for it to be a guessing game. You can use [Instance Fleets - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-instance-fleet.html) to specify multiple:

- Instance Types

> For each fleet, you specify up to five EC2 instance types. Amazon EMR
> chooses any combination of these EC2 instance types to fulfill your
> target capacities.

- Availability Zones

> When you use instance fleets, you can specify multiple EC2 subnets
> within a VPC, each corresponding to a different Availability Zone.
> Instances are always provisioned in only one Availability Zone.

See also: [New – Amazon EMR Instance Fleets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-emr-instance-fleets/)